# A noncommutative analogy of the tube lemma

Tags: gn.general-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, banach-algebras, gelfand-duality

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are two unital commutative Banach algebras. Assume that $\phi \in \mathcal{M} (A)$ is an element of the maximal Ideal space. Define $\alpha: A\hat{\otimes} B \to \mathbb{C}\otimes B\simeq  B$ with $\alpha=\phi \otimes Id_{B}$.  $\;$Put $I=\ker \alpha$. Assume that $J$ is an ideal in $A\hat{\otimes} B$ with $J+ I=A\hat{\otimes} B$.

> 1.Is there an ideal $K$ in $A$ with $K\hat{\otimes} B \subset J$ and $(K\hat{\otimes} B )+ I= A\hat{\otimes} B$?
>
> 2.Consider the same question for two (pure algebraic) complex unital algebras, so we remove  $"\hat{}"$ from the above tensor products. and $\phi$ is an algebra morphism from $A$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

This question is motivated by the "tube lemma" in general topology. So the answer to this question is  "yes" for commutative $C^{*}$ algebras $A$ and $B$

We can consider the same question for (noncommutative) $C^{*}$ algebras $A$ and $B$, an irreducible representation $\phi:  A \to B(H)$ and $\alpha: A\otimes B \to B(H) \otimes B$ and $I=\ker  \alpha$.

**I explain that why I think that this is a noncommutative version of the tube lemma:**

In general, assume that $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $F$ and $K$ are two  closed sets in $X$, then they are two disjoint set iff $I_{F}+I_{K}=C(X)$ where $I_{F}$ is the ideal in $C(X)$ which consists all $g\in C(X)$  with $g(F)=0$ . Now assume that $F=\{x_{0}\}\times Y$ is a slice in $X\times Y$. Then $I_{F}$ has an algebraic description as the above $I=\ker \alpha$, in my question. If $U$ is  an open set containing this slice, then $U^{c}$ and  the slice are two disjoint closed set. So the inclusion $\{x_{0}\}\times Y \subset U$ implies that $J+I=C(X)$ where $J=I_{U^{c}}$.

Comment: I removed the "ask WBJ" tag, which if it is to remain used should be used meaningfully. (WBJ is a Banach space theorist, not an operator algebraist)

Comment: The repeated editing of this question seems excessive.

Comment: @NikWeaver I tried to construct a "non unital case" but I need to the following. do you think that the answer to this question is obvious? :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768054/two-disjoint-closed-sets-in-a-locally-compact-hausdorff-space

Comment: That is :what is  the algebraic analogy of "Two disjoint closed sets" in non unital case?

Comment: @AliTaghavi, it is certainly best if you do this «trying» in your computer and, when you have gotten something you are content with, edit the question here. Otherwise, ten edits become rather immediately disruptive of *the whole site*. Please avoid this.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I was not aware that several edit make problem for the site. I am sorry for several editing.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: the answer to your stackexchange question is yes. Go to the one-point compactification of $X$ to reduce to the unital case.

Comment: @NikWeaver   the problem is that it is possible that the point at infity is a limit point for both $F$ and $K$. so in one point compactification we do not have two disjoint **closed** set. Am I mistaken?

Comment: So if there is  a counter example to my question in stackexchange, a new topological invariant would appear: a locally compact Hausdorff space satisfies this invariant if for every two disjoint closed subsets $F$ and $K$, $I_{F}+I_{K}=C_{0}(X)$. then it would be interesting to translate this invariant in a pure algebraic language for a (non commutative) algebra.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: Given any $f \in C_0(X)$, consider the function on $F \cup K \cup \{\infty\}$ which agrees with $f$ on $K \cup \{\infty\}$ and is zero on $F \cup \{\infty\}$. It is continuous by the gluing lemma and extends to $X \cup \{\infty\}$ by Tietze. Call the extension $g$; then $g + (f - g)$ is the desired decomposition showing $f \in I_F + I_K$.

Comment: @NikWeaver thank you for your nice argument.