# tensor product of the disc algebra with itself

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A=\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{D})$ be the disc algebra. Is there a cross norm on $A\otimes A$, which is compatible to the Banach algebra multiplication, such that the resulting Banach algebra has a $C^{*}$  algebraic structure.(That is, it has  a $C^{*}$ involution).

I think that the most obvious obstruction for the disc algebra to  be a $C^{*}$  algebra is that it does not have a zero divisor. So  a related question ; Is it true to say that every Banach algebra cross norm on $A\otimes A$ gives us  a Banach algebra without zero divisor?

Comment: The answer to your first question is no, because for any reasonable cross norm, the map $f\otimes g \to f(0)g$ will be a continuous algebra homomorphism of $A\otimes_\alpha A$ onto $A$. Banach algebra quotients of (algebras isomorphic to) abelian $C^*$-algebras are themselves abelian $C^*$-algebras, and $A$ is not isomorphic as a Banach algebra to any $C(X)$, so $A\otimes_\alpha A$ cannot be isomorphic as a Banach algebra to $C(X)$. The second question might be more interesting.

Comment: Dear @Yemon thank you very much. Your comment is very interesting. It is also strange because in this question I was (very indirectly), somehow motivated by the following question:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164169/a-noncommutative-analogy-of-the-tube-lemma. on the other hand your map is $\phi \otimes Id$ in the above question. First  Does your statement  a consequence of the fact that the ideal in $C^{*}$ algebras are $*$-closed? second: Do you think that the tube lemma is true forthe disc algebra? Is the projective tensor product a reasonable norm? Thanks again for interesting comment.

Comment: Ali: 1) yes 2) don't know 3) yes, and for the disc algebra, the injective tensor product also gives you a Banach algebra. See Tomiyama's 1960 paper http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tmj/1178244494 for more on tensor products of commutative Banach algebras